# How to check if int is 5 smaller than another int?

Tags: android, string

I want my app to check if the current version code is 5+ versions behind than that on the server.

If current version code is `100` and version code on server is `105` or higher , it should show a toast "app is obsolete". But the problem is, it always shows this toast, the code on my server is `104`.

```
  if (updateVersionCode >= info.versionCode - 5) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "force update, app is 5 versions behind!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        //not obsolete
    }
```

here is my full code for the geeks-

```
public static void compareVersions(Context context) {
    // 1) get local apk version code
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // 2) get version code from downloaded .txt file
    int updateVersionCode = info.versionCode;
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, "ver.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            updateVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle errors!
    }

    // 3) compare Versions
    if (updateVersionCode > info.versionCode) {
        // download apk file
        context.startService(new Intent(context,
                NSOMUHDownloadApkService.class));
        Toast.makeText(context, "updates are available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "up to date!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (updateVersionCode >= info.versionCode - 5) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "force update, app is 5 versions behind!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        //not obsolete
    }
}
```

PS: It downloads the version from server in a .txt file and reads it.

Comment: You can see `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subtracting where you should be adding. Change your comparison to:

```
if (updateVersionCode >= info.versionCode + 5) {
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have me mistaken with a pop star; my name is Jeremiah Megel.

Answer (score 1):

Try my below logic using temp variable.

```
int temp=(updateVersionCode -info.versionCode);
if ((temp>0 && temp==5) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "force update, app is 5 versions behind!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
} else {
    //not obsolete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have flipped your sign in the comparison. You test if the new version is bigger than the current version minus five, and that should always be true. Try:

```
if (updateVersionCode >= info.versionCode + 5)
```

as your condition.